# Why is my script running if run with cli but not with crontab?

Tags: bash, python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cron, wsl2

On WSL Ubuntu 20.04 I have two scripts (one sh and one python) that run perfectly if I launch them with bash, but not with cron.

The second (python) script is supposed to run just if the first (bash) succeded. I therefore used an `&&` operator.

If I run `/mnt/c/folder/first.sh && /home/myself/miniconda3/bin/python /mnt/c/folder/second.py`, however if I have this very same line in crontab, **the second script does not work**.

I have tried to include the line `/home/myself/miniconda3/bin/python /mnt/c/folder/second.py` into the bash script, but also that doesn't work.
This python script makes use of an environment variable to work, I wonder if that is the reason. Although I have tried to include `. $HOME/.profile;` in the crontab right before the command above; without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This python script makes use of an environment variable to work, I wonder if that is the reason.

Yes, when executed via `/bin/sh` with a command (as `anacron` is doing by default), the shell is not a login shell, so `~/.profile` doesn't get sourced.

> Although I have tried to include . $HOME/.profile; in the crontab right before the command above; without success.

This worked for me.  I added `export abc=123` to my `~/.profile` and added the following to `/etc/crontab`:

```
*  *    * * *   username    . $HOME/.profile && true && echo $abc >> $HOME/crontest
```

The resulting `~/crontest` correctly displayed a `123` for every minute passed.

Another alternative would be to force the `sh` to run as a login shell (`-l`), and pass in your script via `-c`:

```
*  *    * * *   username    sh -lc 'true && echo $abc >> $HOME/crontest'
```